# How to send/receive messages between processes with pid

Tags: message-queue, messaging, message-passing

How can I send and receive messages between processes knowing just their pids?
Without allocatimg shared queues or mailboxes or without mappimg pid into socket ports...
Maybe what I'm asking is at a very low level (os level maybe) but I'm interested into it.
Thanks

Comment: Which OS do you mean? Windows has `PostThreadMessage`, POSIX systems have `kill`.

Comment: I meant Posix/Unix...kill is used for signals, isn't it? I'm referring just to messages...

Comment: Or maybe direct message passing, point to point

Comment: A 'message' is a broad term. Having only a pid and without any preparation, you can send a signal. That's all. Sending any data would require some additional OS objects (socket, message queue, file etc.) But, well, why not to open a UNIX-domain socket which is identified by the pid?

Comment: "But, well, why not to open a UNIX-domain socket which is identified by the pid?", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Just let a process create a UNIX-domain socket, say, at /tmp/<own-pid>, and listen on it. Other processes can send messages to the socket. DGRAM sockets would suit better I think.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about UNIX-domain sockets. Our teacher showed us only AF_INET sockets. I'll make an attempt at once :)

Answer (score 2):

On linux you can open up the file `/proc/[pid]/fd/0` to gain access to the stdin of the process with pid `[pid]`.  You can also open up arbitrary file descriptors on a process by changing the `0` to something else.

Comment: Nice. But isn't stdin mapped to `0` file descriptor, not `1`? Also, for an interactive process, its input would be symlinked to a terminal device (like /dev/pts/1), and writing to it would just output the data at the terminal rather then feed it into stdin.

Comment: You're right, my mistake, it is file descriptor `0`.  But the files present in the `/proc/[pid]/fd` directory are symlinks to the file descriptors themselves.  Test it out, it works.

Comment: I just tested it with my shell. Sending anything to its fd/0 just prints that out rather than makes the shell execute the input. It's because shell's descriptors are all symlinked to /dev/pts/1. But it certainly works, e.g., for pipelined processes (I can write in the middle of the pipeline).

Comment: Interesting. Probably it's something with how bash handles redirects. But `echo ls >> /proc/<pid-of-shell>/fd/0` doesn't work for me.

Comment: It might have something to do with the way that readline is implemented.  If it connects directly to the terminal device rather than the file descriptor, that would explain the issue.